# Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction

Tags: ios5

I m using Animation in table view cell...Animation is working fine when cell is totally visible.if any cell is partially visible at that time due to Animation my app is getting crashed at the line   [_Mytableviewobject endUpdates];

Crash Log=Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction'

code  section:

```
-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)sectionOpened
{
     //ENSLog(self, _cmd);
    [_caseTable reloadData];
    NSInteger countOfRowsToInsert = 1;
    SectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:sectionOpened];
    sectionInfo.open = YES;


    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToInsert; i++) 
    {
        [indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionOpened]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSInteger previousOpenSectionIndex = self.openSectionIndex;
    if (previousOpenSectionIndex != NSNotFound)
    {
        SectionInfo *previousOpenSection = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:previousOpenSectionIndex];
        previousOpenSection.open = NO;
        [previousOpenSection.headerView toggleOpenWithUserAction:NO];
        NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = 1;
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++)
        {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:previousOpenSectionIndex]];
        }
    }

    // Style the animation so that there's a smooth flow in either direction.
    UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation;
    UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation;
    if (previousOpenSectionIndex == NSNotFound || sectionOpened < previousOpenSectionIndex) 
    {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    }
    else
    {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
    }

    // Apply the updates.
    [_caseTable beginUpdates];
    [_caseTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
    [_caseTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
    [_caseTable endUpdates];
    //ExNSLog(self, _cmd);

    self.openSectionIndex = sectionOpened;
    //ExNSLog(self, _cmd);

}




-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)sectionClosed
{
     //ENSLog(self, _cmd);
    SectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:sectionClosed];
    sectionInfo.open = NO;
    NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [_caseTable numberOfRowsInSection:sectionClosed];
    if (countOfRowsToDelete > 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) 
        {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionClosed]];
        }
        [_caseTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    self.openSectionIndex = NSNotFound;
     //ExNSLog(self, _cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes i also face this type of problem,do one thing just remove footer view.

Comment: That doesn't explain *why*. I got the same exception when scrolling (not deleting or adding rows, only when scrolling), and it's a PITA.

Comment: Proposed solution doesn't work for me either. Might help if someone can explain why this solution works for some

Answer (score 44):

I experienced the same crash when trying to use a dummy footer to remove potential "empty" table view cells.

The solution was to get rid of

```
tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
tableView:heightForFooterInSection:
```

and replace them with the following, in viewDidLoad :

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution! Works perfectly, and allows for empty cells to be hidden completely. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if you need a sticky footer view that stays at the bottom of the screen?  You can't use tableFooterView for that :(  I need a sticky footer and resizable cells but i keep getting this crash!

Comment: What if you actually need section footer (so each section has a footer)?. Table view footer is not a replacement for that.

Answer (score 6):

it seems to happen when set `tableview`

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

while `tableview` style set `Plain` instead of `Grouped` style

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after the ios 7 update : crash appeared during a "deleteRowsAtIndexPaths" for expand/collapse stuff in my table view.

Surprisingly, I have solved this issue by using heightForHeaderInsection instead of heightForFooterInSection.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1; // it was 0 before the fix
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0; // it was 1 before the fix
}
```

This issue has been reported (https://devforums.apple.com/message/795349).

Comment: can you send me some demo code of expand and collapse of table view

Comment: This worked for me.  Not sure why.  Just an iOS 7 bug it seems.

Comment: This should be higher up in the list. It is indeed an OS bug, and the bug pertains only to section footers (not headers). So for those of us that must have section dividers, the solution is to use a header instead of a footer. Perhaps not ideal, but better than other options proposed here (use tableView footer, get rid of section footers etc.).

Answer (score 4):

You can use header of next section
my same answer is here

- create empty section
- use its header instead of footer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297703/788798

Answer (score 3):

For people experienced this issue after iOS 7 updates:
Check the view frame of the section footer view. If it overlaps with the tableview cell. System throws this exception.

Comment: I think its real bug for iOS 7.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2. And it seems to be fixed on iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: Nope, this is still present after 7.0.3. At least in 7.1, 7.1.1 and 7.1.2

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in iOS. I filed a bug report and they came back saying its a duplicate of 14898413. This bug is still marked as open in apple bug reporter.

Options for fixes: 
1) Remove footer
2) Instead of deleting rows, begin and end updates reload the table

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and crash whenever I would scroll to the bottom of the tableview and try to delete cells and insert sections my solution was to scroll the tableview back to the top before calling `[tableview beginsUpdates]` using the tableviews content offset. With this solution I didn't have to change my section header or footer at all.

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```

Comment: Also worked for me. Unfortunately this fix only works when the tableview's content size is bigger than it's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this bug by calling reloadData() for last section:

```
func expandSectionPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let object = items[sender.tag]
    object.expanded = !object.expanded
    sender.selected = object.expanded
    var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
    for i in 0..<7 {
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: sender.tag))
    }
    if object.expanded {
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else {
        // strange crash when deleting rows from the last section //
        if sender.tag < numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView) - 1 {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem  - exception 'Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction' in [[self tableView] endUpdates]; I solved it by catching the exception and making the endUpdates second time.

```
[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
@try
{
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
@catch (NSException* exception)
{
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: This did get around the crash, but it led to an incorrect layout for me. It appears to collapse my footer.