# UItableview animation crash occuring while insert and delete

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

Terminating app due to `uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException`,

**Reason:** `Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction`
while using

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
```

Comment: Try to set the animation as nil. There will be a problem with animation.

Comment: You may take a look to this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664766/cell-animation-stop-fraction-must-be-greater-than-start-fraction

Comment: Are you using any Headers/Footers?

Comment: yes I am using headers and footers.

Answer (score 0):

Its bug on iOS7.x The solution was to remove the below delegates,

```
tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
tableView:heightForFooterInSection:
```

and replace them with the below line of code in viewDidLoad.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Well, but this doesn't work for cases where you need section not table view footer.