# UITableView crashing when deleting items at the end of it

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I have a UITableView with a bunch of sections / rows. I've been getting hammered by a weird bug where when I delete a row, my program will crash. My delete code is as follows:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSMutableArray* myArray = [self.myArray mutableCopy];
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.myArray = myArray;

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The debugger throws me an error on `endUpdates` with the following error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Now, to save everyone some time, I have extensively tested and verified that everything is absolutely correct with my datasource updating and my deleting the right indexPath. I just noticed that the issue only occurs when I am scrolled all the way to the bottom of my tableview such that I cannot scroll anymore, and then delete a cell in the visible area on the page.

I can delete properly anywhere else in my tableview so long as there is more content offscreen below it, but once I'm at the end of the tableview, a delete will throw this error.

If it helps, I basically have a `UITableViewController` (plain style) in a `UIPageViewController`. I've tried removing the UIPageViewController and just pushing onto the UITableViewController, but this error still occurs.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this?

EDIT:

Seems like a lot of people are still thinking it might be the array, but here is the thing. I can move my sections around in my tableview (all sections have rows that can be deleted). I will always get the crash when deleting rows in any visible section when the tableview is fully scrolled to the bottom. This code fragment is abstracted and used in all sections, so I'm pretty sure the code is correct.

When I delete a row in a section where the tableview is centered in the middle, I've noticed that the row swipes up to delete, even though I said to use a fade animation. The animation animates the rows or sections below it up, which is correct behavior. I feel this might be related to when the tableview is at the end of its content, it is trying to scroll something up, but there is nothing there.

`HACK:`
*A hack that I implemented just now is to put a plain UIView the same size as my tableView in tableView.tableFooterView. This causes my tableView to have more scrollable size, which I do NOT like, but with it, the crashes do not occur since there is more scrollable space to move up when last cell is deleted. I'd appreciate a solution where I don't have to do this.*

Well, it only seems to work if the footer view is very large. If I make the footer view smaller, like 100 pixels, it still crashes if you are scrolled to the edge of the tableview.

`Stack Trace:` (The debugger will first crash to the endUpdates line in the code above, and when I hit play on the debugger twice more, this stack trace comes)

```
2014-07-18 05:52:41.314 ScriptChart[26419:905949] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c9f055 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d1d8a1c objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b6d92a -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 954
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010b86c424 __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke915 + 177
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b803a4c +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 473
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b803ca1 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 57
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b86bfc3 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2803
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b8660b2 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 11934
    8   ScriptChart                         0x000000010863f272 -[SCLabListNoteSection deleteCell:] + 1250
    9   ScriptChart                         0x00000001085e127f __45-[SCLabPanelTableViewCell infoButtonPressed:]_block_invoke127 + 207
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b9e0fe7 -[UIAlertController _fireOffActionOnTargetIfValidForAction:] + 55
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010b9e14d5 __85-[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:]_block_invoke + 30
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010b892bc4 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1118
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b894d8e __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 133
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010bec4123 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 110
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b8037fd -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 326
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010b7ec42a -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 209
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b7ec760 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 76
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b4dff9e _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d537d64 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d523f82 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 941
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c07ae9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bca46b __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bc9a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010db6cabf GSEventRunModal + 161
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010b792cf8 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    26  ScriptChart                         0x00000001085ca153 main + 179
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d56c145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: does your table view have a footer? there is a bug which causes crashes sometimes when the table view has a footer, i experienced the same lately and solved the issue by removing the footer.

Comment: I have not added any footers, but it does have custom section headers.

Comment: hmm.. the error message is about inserting nil into an array. I would thing the culprit is `@[indexPath]` ... are you sure indexPath is not nil at this point ? Which row exactly does the crash occur?

Comment: this part of the code is correct, I think your array is the problem.

Comment: My array is fine. The error is not occurring there at all. I logged both indexPath and the cell at that indexPath, both are not nil before starting this animation block, and the array has 1 item in it. IndexPath row is 0, which is correct since there is only 1 item in the section. I use this same code everywhere, and it works for every other section.

Comment: Which methods of `UITableViewDelegate` you have implemented? Including implementations in custom parent classes if they exist.

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. Also, heightForHeaderInSection, and viewForHeaderInSection, and willDisplayCell.

Comment: Can you post the call stack that you see in Xcode when error occurs? So we can see which functions were called prior to error.

Comment: Why can't you use "[self.myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" to delete the object from array, as you have a mutable array already.

Comment: self.myArray is defined as an NSArray. I *should* make the last line `self.myArray = [myArray copy];`, but I am lazy and don't want the performance hit even though it is probably minimal.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. I've noticed this happening when the tableview was in a certain scroll position where the deletion of the cell would cause some other cells above to come back down. But like you, mine crashes on endUpdates with the same insertObject:atIndex: error. What version of Xcode are you using? I'm on Xcode6-beta4 and iOS8-beta4. I'm hoping this is just an Xcode6/iOS8 bug. I've noticed that iOS 8 also needs heightForRowAtIndexPath: to be implemented, even if you just want the default 44-point height of a table view cell, so maybe they just have to fix table views.

Comment: I'm running the same as you. I do have custom heights, so I implemented those methods. Have you tried just setting the row height via `tableview.rowHeight = 44.0f;`?

Comment: I don't mind implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath: and returning 44.0f (which works fine), I rather just mentioned it as optimistic evidence that maybe Apple has some table view bugs in iOS 8, and so hopefully our problem is just one of them! :)

Comment: Suggests to me that number of rows is where the problem lies

Comment: I've filed a bug report with Apple in the meantime.

Comment: Seems like it is a known issue with Apple as my bug report was marked as a Duplicate. Hopefully it will be fixed.

Comment: Seems like it was fixed in iOS 8 beta 5. Haven't had the issue since upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath? This may be causing the crash.

Comment: I am not, but I suspect that the internal UITableView code is.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered setting the UITableView style to plain rather than grouped solved the issue for me. You can find the setting by selecting your table in the Storyboard.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261510/585227

Comment: I can't use Plain as a style as I don't want floating headers