# UITableView tableFooterView may cause crash?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I add an add `UIButton` to a `UITableFooterView` in a `UITableView`.If I touched this button,the action is add a new cell("*insertRowsAtIndexPaths*") for the tableView.Most of the time it works well, but sometimes it maybe crash like:

```
2013-02-04 15:00:56.139 browser2345HD[3156:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableViewSupport.m:2596
2013-02-04 15:00:56.139 browser2345HD[3156:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e6a012 0x1c8fe7e 0x1e69e78 0x1419f35 0xb365df 0xb348f0 0xb358d8 0x970666 0x96cc67    0x978f95 0x978fc3 0x8ba4b 0x962fa73 0x9645c62 0x964683b 0x963015f 0x9700ac4 0x9700b09   0x96300c9 0x963e977 0x9630fd8 0x963eba7 0x963f393 0x963eba7 0x963f393 0x963eba7 0x963f393   0x963eba7 0x963f393 0x96f931d 0x973e387 0x9739717 0x9740ff3 0x1ddfbf5 0x1ddf962 0x1e10bb6   0x1e0ff44 0x1e0fe1b 0x2bd17e3 0x2bd1668 0x8cb65c 0x2955 0x2855)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

**Can anyone solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar behavior with this: [UITableView : crash when adding a section footer view in empty section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297703/1698467)

Try to use header of section below instead footer of this one.

Good luck! :)