# Why am I getting an assert Error When trying to Delete a section in a tableview ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with some sections, which all have a footer, and then I have a tableViewFooter on the Tableview itself.

If I scroll down to the bottom of my tableview and delete the last item(therefore deleting the section altogether) in any sections above the last section (second last and up) it gives me this error

```
2014-02-21 13:19:55.066 xxxx[5436:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableViewSupport.m:2661
Uncaught exception: Cell animation stop fraction must be greater than start fraction
```

at endUpdates

this is my code

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if(indexPath != nil){
        TableSection * sec = [self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSMutableDictionary *dic =[sec.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        Product* product = [dic valueForKey:PRODUCT];


        //removing the item in the section
        [sec.items removeObject:dic];

        //deleting item from products 
        NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (Product *p in self.dataCon.listPersister.products) {
            if ([p.product.objId isEqualToString: product.product.objId]) {
                [temp addObject:p];
            }
        }

        for (Product *p in temp) {
            [self.dataCon.listPersister.products removeObject:p];
        }


        //if it was the last object in section, delete the section else just delete the single row

        if(sec.items.count == 0)
        {


            [self.sections removeObject:sec];
            [self.footers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        } else
        {

            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            USFooterView *footer = [self.footers objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            footer.totalLabel.text = [self.dataCon.listPersister getTotalForShopId:sec.title];
            self.footerView.totalLabel.text = [self.dataCon.listPersister getTotalForAllProducts];
        }

    }


    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

I had the same code earlier, just without my tableView and table sections having footers, where it worked, so I think they might be the problem, but I'm not entirely sure that's the reason it's acting up.

I have seen this post

[UITableView tableFooterView may cause crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722523/uitableview-tablefooterview-may-cause-crash)

And the post that it links to, but that didn't help me.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19861743/1179863 ?

Comment: I just tried some of the suggestions I hadn't tried earlier but I have seen that post before and none of the answers solved my issue, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a "fix", but I'm avoiding the use of sectionFooter, because that seems to be bugged.

I created an extra cell at the end of each section, with the same setup I had for my footer View before, and made that last cell not editable with

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableSection * sec = [self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    if (sec.items.count != indexPath.row) {
        return YES;
    } else
        return NO;
}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return [sec.items count] +1 ;

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"normalcell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"footercell";


TableSection * sec = [self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

if (indexPath.row != sec.items.count) {
    //use normal type of cell


    return cell;
} else{
    //use footer type of cell

    return cell;
}

}
```

So the last cell Imitates a "footer", but it's not stuck to the bottom of the frame, but I'll have to live with that. It's better than crashes.

Answer (score 1):

In the else statement you delete row from table view:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

But not from data source. Delete row from array which you use as data source and it should works.

Comment: I'm removing the item from the datasource in the 2 loops earlier. First loop I'm finding the products that match. Second loop I delete them from datasource. The reason I'm deleting the row down there is because I don't need to remove the row if I delete the section altogether. I've tried deleting the row always but that doesn't change things other than the animation looks a bit weird because it tries to remove the section and the row separately.

Comment: Are you sure you remove just one object from that loop and it's exactly on the same location as indexPath you use to remove object from tableview? You do if indexPath != nil, and after that you remove object from your data source in loop, why you don't remove object base on that indexPath. I believe the object you remove from the array doesn't match the object you remove from tableview and the app crashes?

Comment: It's a different error you're talking about. You get this instead

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

And that's not the issue here.

Comment: But this is however a very good answer to that specific issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using UITableViewRowAnimationLeft or UITableViewRowAnimationRight as the delete row animation(deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:).

It crashed for me when using UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic, but not with the other two. I have not tried all of them but it seems to be a bug with the animation code for some of the options.