# Assertion failure when deleting a uitableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation, assertions

I am deleting cells in my tableview when they are selected. Each cell represents its own section so I am deleting them as follows

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self.myData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

But sometimes- not always - am getting this error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIViewAnimation initWithView:indexPath:endRect:endAlpha:startFraction:endFraction:curve:animateFromCurrentPosition:shouldDeleteAfterAnimation:editing:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableViewSupport.m:2661
```

Don't understand the cause...

Here is the dump of the tableview and its layer

```
Printing description of self->_tableView:
<UITableView: 0x17043200; frame = (20 40; 280 160); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16653330>; layer = <CALayer: 0x166dbc70>; contentOffset: {0, 35}>
(lldb) po 0x166dbc70
<CALayer:0x166dbc70; position = CGPoint (160 120); bounds = CGRect (0 35; 280 160); delegate = <UITableView: 0x17043200; frame = (20 40; 280 160); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16653330>; layer = <CALayer: 0x166dbc70>; contentOffset: {0, 35}>; sublayers = (<CALayer: 0x1667f320>, <CALayer: 0x16556400>, <CALayer: 0x16763220>, <CALayer: 0x165d8440>, <CALayer: 0x1662d260>, <CALayer: 0x1674e010>); masksToBounds = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; backgroundColor = <CGColor 0x1668ef70> [<CGColorSpace 0x166868e0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] ( 0 0 )>
```

Comment: Is the number of rows for section returning self.myData.count ?

Comment: yes. the data source is correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934747/why-am-i-getting-an-assert-error-when-trying-to-delete-a-section-in-a-tableview